# How to determine web page cpu usage?

Tags: mac, firefox

When I have a lot of web pages open in Firefox, sometimes the Firefox cpu usage can grow to 95% or more, making all of the pages slow.  I've noticed that closing pages on certain sites can significantly lower the cpu usage but it is just a trial and error process, and I don't really want to close the pages if they aren't using significant cpu.

Is there some way to determine which pages (or add-ons) are using the most cpu, so that I can concentrate on closing those?  Or some way to stop pages that are not even on visible tabs from using the cpu at all?

I've looked for a Firefox add-on that could report the information but haven't found any, and some add-ons I've tried such as Firebug actually seem to make the cpu usage far worse.

I am using Firefox on Mac OS X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Chrome for this. It has the ability to tell you how much memory is consumed by each tab individually. [Chrome for Mac](http://www.google.com/chrome/intl/en/eula_dev.html?dl=mac).

[image]

Comment: He's on Mac OS X. He can't use chrome yet.

Comment: Stats for nerds... that's funny. (What's in there?)

Comment: Sure he can. It's just not *officially* available.

Comment: Chrome for Mac: http://www.google.com/chrome/intl/en/eula_dev.html?dl=mac

Comment: @Zifre - http://images.google.com/images?q=chrome+stats+for+nerds&hl=en&sa=N&um=1&imgsz=xxlarge

Comment: This looks very nice, and might make it worth switching to Chrome.  If only Chrome supported Firefox add-ons...

Comment: @Mark4o. Chrome will be supporting addons soon. Hang in there ;) At the very least, you can use it for now to test your CPU usage per tab.

Comment: The Chrome beta for Mac still doesn't support the Task Manager yet.  :(

Comment: The current Chrome Mac beta now includes the Task Manager and extension support!  I guess I should have known that "Plug-in: Shockwave Flash" would be high on the cpu list, and one plug-in process is used for all pages using Flash.  At least it lets you End Process, which is enough to accept this answer.

Answer (score 3):

Firefox 4.x should [add multiprocess support](http://mozillalinks.org/wp/2009/05/future-firefox-will-be-multiprocess/), which should solve your problem

Answer (score 2):

It's 2022 now. One can go to `about:performance` in firefox to show resource consumption by tab/addon/subframe.